# jquery datepicker internationalization based on user agent

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm having trouble with jQuerydatepicker. As I'm pretty sure, it surely is easy to solve. But I don't know much about JavaScript and jQuery. So I'm asking for help!
The thing is like this:
I have a form which has a `data-datepickerlang` attribute (which I set to whatever the user agent language is).

```html
<input class="hasDatepicker" data-datepicker="True" data-datepickerlang="es" data-val="true" ...
```

So far, my JavaScript function looks like this:

```
$(":input[data-datepicker]").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```

Which displays the datepicker, but always in English format. How do I take that "es" from `data-datepickerlang`, and tell datepicker to format the date like dd/mm/yyyy ?
Thanks!

Edit: I also need it to be able to show it in English format `mm/dd/yyyy`. Depending in the locale of the browser. That 'es' value I got it from razor

```
(@{ var x = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages[0].Substring(0, 2);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

their are localize option in jquery datepicker this code example from jquery ui Dochttp://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization

```
    $(function() {
var regional = $(":input[data-datepicker]");
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[regional.attr('data-datepickerlang')]);
      });
```

Comment: But that actually hardcodes the format. I get the 'es' from razor. I need it to be able to use dd/mm/yyyy, and if I change my locale options to english, it should be able to show it in mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: I've seen it. But I don't know how to get the value of 'data-datepickerlang' to use it in the call.

Comment: So, how does it should be applied to my function? Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you, but that doesn't work for me. I changed #datepicker with :input[data-datepicker], but still doesn't work... :(

Comment: are you using asp.net MVC ?

Comment: Yes, I am... And as you can see, I'm pretty new to all of this

Comment: sorry I don't know asp.net MVC Render engine

Comment: I don't think it's a razor thing. Because I have the html attribute if I see the source, but I don't know why your code doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this way:

```
$(function() {


var regional = $(":input[data-datepicker]").attr("data-datepickerlang");
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional[regional]);
$(":input[data-datepicker]").datepicker({

    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
}, $.datepicker.regional[regional.valueOf()]);

}
)
```

Wich is basically what darkSlayer told me to do. But don't know why it wasn't working.
Thanks!